# How to prove that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} F_n$ doesn't have to be a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

**"Inductive transition"**

Let $F_1$ some subalgebra. Let define for all $n \in \mathbb N$ set $F_{n+1}$ as the class of all sets representable in the form of a countable union and countable intersection of sets from $F_n$.

I want to prove that $\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} F_n$ doesn't even have to be $\sigma$-algebra. Why is this true?

Help please, or links, maybe this is a known property, but I'm a beginner.